# horizontal and vertical separator line in UICollectionview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I want to make separator lines between collection View cell with a specific color(grey), without changing the BG color of Collection View.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sodTw.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UIView inside the collectionViewCell and width 1px or 2px

Comment: As of now, I used a UIView in the cell, but I need a proper approach for this.

Answer (score 0):

Change the background color of the superview to grey and add edge insects to the collectionView using the below code in viewDidLoad life cycle method:-

```
private let spacing:CGFloat = 2.0

let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: spacing, left: spacing, bottom: spacing, right: spacing)
layout.minimumLineSpacing = spacing
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = spacing
self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

Comment: No, I don't want to change the Background color of collection View.

Comment: You can add a view as a superview of collectionView and change it's background color, if you don't want to change the color of collectionView.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more. I tried to add a view on the collection view but it did not look like a separator line at the bottom of the collection view(It seems like I change the background color of collection View).

Comment: My collection View cell is dynamic.

Comment: I didn't get you. Can you share a screenshot for the same.